# ButtonDownFcn with an argument in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface, event-handling, callback

I have a patch which I have included below and I want to add an additional ButtonDownFcn to the patch. When I do the second option the code does not work I get to many output arguments.

Original patch

```
for i = 1:10
    counter = counter+1;
    hpatch(counter) = patch([x(17) x(18) x(1) x(1)],[y(17) y(18) y(1) y(1)],[0 0 0 0],...
    'Parent',hAx,'ButtonDownFcn', ['winopen(''' file(counter) ''');']));
end
```

New desired patch

```
for i = 1:10
    counter = counter+1;
    hpatch(counter) = patch([x(17) x(18) x(1) x(1)],[y(17) y(18) y(1) y(1)],[0 0 0 0],...
    'Parent',hAx,'ButtonDownFcn', ['winopen(''' file(counter) ''');'],...
    'ButtonDownFcn', @saveClickData(counter));
end
```

Here is the function

```
saveClickData(counter)
```

should it be this?:

```
saveClickData(source,event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
patch(X,Y,Z, 'ButtonDownFcn',{@saveClickData, counter})
```

Then define the callback function as:

```
function saveClickData(src,evt,counter)
    winopen( file(counter) );

    %# do additional stuff..
end
```

Make sure to define this function as a **nested function**, so that it has access to its parent function workspace including the `file` variable.